Webpack style-loader not injecting CSS into the DOM
Problem:
The CSS is not being injected into the DOM using the style-loader package. There are no errors on build (which runs webpack --config webpack.config.js). The CSS is being placed into the bundle.js file but not into the ui.html file as intended.
Packages:
The webpack version is 5.91.0, html-webpack-plugin is 5.6.0, css-loader 7.1.2 and style loader is 4.0.0 or higher.
Steps to resolve the issue: checked file paths and structure, checked the HTML file has a valid structure, packages are installed and performed a clean build.
webpack.config.js file
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/ui.html',
            filename: 'ui.html'
        })
    ],
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    cache: false
};

console.log('Webpack configuration loaded successfully.');

index.js file
import "./main.css";
import "./code.js";

console output on build
Webpack configuration loaded successfully.
asset bundle.js 1.11 MiB [emitted] (name: main)
asset ui.html 3.2 KiB [emitted]
runtime modules 972 bytes 5 modules
cacheable modules 406 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/ 8.58 KiB
    modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.84 KiB 6 modules
    modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.74 KiB
      ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/sourceMaps.js 505 bytes [built] [code generated]
      ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/api.js 2.25 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./src/ 397 KiB
    modules by path ./src/components/*.js 43.6 KiB 3 modules
    modules by path ./src/*.js 11.3 KiB 2 modules
    modules by path ./src/*.css 342 KiB
      ./src/main.css 1.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
      ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/main.css 341 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.91.0 compiled successfully in 1026 ms

